# How can I stop the "Pylance extension is available" popups?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

When I launch VS Code in a folder containing python files, the program
often pops up a window in the lower right part of the screen to notify me
that the Pylance extension is available. It does this when files are reopened
from a previous instance of VS Code, and also when I open a new python file.

It does this even though I previously deleted Pylance from the list
of recommended extensions.

How can I stop this popup from repeatedly appearing?

Comment: Is this in VS Code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question, I think it needs more "Details and/or clarity". Please consider the guidelines in the help center [*"How do I ask a good question?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It would be important to have more details about the conditions in which this happens.

Comment: Whenever I first open a Python file after launching code, a popup appears in the lower right corner to notify me that pylance extension is available, even after i deleted it from the recommended extensions list. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I was asking if you are talking about VS Code. It was closed as unclear because it was not clear if when you say "code" do you mean VS Code. You need to clearly describe your problem and [tag your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), because people who don't use VS Code will not understand what you are talking about. I went ahead and [edited your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65432360/revisions) to hopefully clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @user2423302 -Please check whether _"python.languageServer": "Pylance",_ is set in "settings.json" (user). Have you considered using "Pylance"? It combines Python extensions to provide many outstanding features such as Python language services, docstrings and so on.